# Solving function containing gamma in Python

Tags: python, solver, gamma-distribution

I'm quite new to programming with python.

I was wondering, if there is a smart way to solve a function, which includes a gamma function with a certain shape and scale.

I already created a function G(x), which is the cdf of a gamma function up to a variable x. Now I want to solve another function including G(x). It should look like: 0=x+2*G(x)-b. Where b is a constant.

My code looks like that:

```
b= 10

def G(x): 
  return gamma.cdf(x,a=4,scale=25)

f = solve(x+2*G(x)-b,x,dict=True)
```

How is it possible to get a real value for G(x) in my solve function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is this `dict=True'?

Comment: dict=True should give me an output like "x=.."

Comment: What are you trying to solve for? The parameters of the Gamma function in the function `x + 2*G(x) - b`?

Comment: I want to solve for x. I know all the paramters in the Gamma Function ( alpha = 4, beta=25), and I know the b in f(x), which is 10. I want to know x for the given parameters in ×+2*G(x) -b. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get roots from a function there are several tools in the scipy module.

Here is a solution with the method fsolve()

```
from scipy.stats import gamma
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def G(x): 
  return gamma.cdf(x,a=4,scale=25)

# we define the function to solve
def f(x,b):
  return x+2*G(x)-b

b = 10
init = 0. # The starting estimate for the roots of f(x) = 0.
roots = fsolve(f,init,args=(b))

print roots
```

Gives output :

```
[9.99844838]
```

Given that G(10) is close to zero this solution seems likely

Sorry, I didn't take into account your dict=True option but I guess you are able to put the result in whatever structure you want without my help.

Comment: Thank you so much! That is exactly what I was searching for!

Answer (score 0):

```
rom sympy import *
# from scipy.stats import gamma
# from sympy.stats import Arcsin, density, cdf
x, y, z, t, gamma, cdf = symbols('x y z t gamma cdf')

#sol = solve([x - 3, y - 1], dict=True)

from sympy.stats import Cauchy, density
from sympy import Symbol
x0 = Symbol("x0")
gamma = Symbol("gamma", positive=True)
z = Symbol("z")
X = Cauchy("x", x0, gamma)
density(X)(z)
print(density(X)(z))

sol = solve([x+2*density(X)(z)-10, y ], dict=True)
print(sol)
```

Or:

```
from scipy.stats import gamma
from sympy import solve, Poly, Eq, Function, exp
from sympy.abc import x, y, z, a, b

def G(x): 
  return gamma.cdf(x,a=4,scale=25)

b= 10

f = solve(x+2*G(x)-b,x,dict=True)
```

[stats cdf gamma solve sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/stats.html)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean. My gamma is already defined, I wanted to access my gamma function G(x) in f(x). I want to solve f(x), which is depending on G(x) so that I get a value for x.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding... You have assigned once a=10 in the global section and other times inside G(x): a=4?  I edited my answer I hope this time I understood you well. I thought that a=10 is x=10, let me correct me...

Comment: Ah my bad, sorry! The a in G(x) is another variable than the a in f(x). I changed the one in f(x) to b. I hope now it gets more clear. My problem is, that I don't know what's the value of x, that's why I want to solve f(x) as a function. I hope now it's clear, thank you so much!

Comment: No problem,  do you have value for x parameter?

Comment: Do you want to have test? https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html

Comment: No, I have no value for x. I want to solve for x, depending on x + 2*G(x) - b, where I know all parameters. Only x is unknown.